# How to animate objects in Unity 3D

Tags: animation, first-person-shooter, unity

Yesterday I played around with Unity 4.6 and I came up with a question about animation.

I have an fps-survival project (most for educational purpose).

I use the default build-in fps camera controller that comes with unity asset and adding a script for head-mob.

Now I animate a "falling" animation. The animation is in the  First Person Controller object. Although I have two "arms" as children in my FPS controller, I want in each frame of my animation to move the arms but when I click in the each arm , the animation window don't show me the correct state of the animation, and I need to get back to where I attach my animation to show again. I don't know what to do. I can't animate the hands in seperate file cause I don't see the falling frame from the FPS controller.(which is more a visual than a technical problem)I want to point out that I need to use both my hand objects and I am preety novice so if you could tell me in steps what to do.

I attach some images bellow to see how my enviroment is setted up.

[When I select the FPS controller](http://prntscr.com/7rgzam)

[After I select each hand](http://prntscr.com/7rgzkb)

Comment: Could you post a screen with the animators?

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the different clips to the FPSController Animator so when you create your fall animation it will be with the others in that controller like walk , run ect ..

You will animate the hands movements and record the movements from the FPS Controller animation window.

[Animation](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/animation)

[The Animator Controller](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/animation/animator-controller)

[image]

Comment: Ok how do I do that? Is there any tutorial? Please If you find the time to write me the steps then I will be thankfull!

Comment: When you click on the Add Clip after you select it like you have in the first image you can then open the tree of your person and through the animation window select the hands. don't just select the hands object because then it will create a additional animator that will not be linked to the one you want. I'll add a link to better explain

Comment: Justin I can't use the aAnimator. I made so many animations. I will lost them all now. :'( Please is there any way to save my work? And I can't find a tutorial tat explains the animator (not the official one is good) It's all so difficult. Aahhh I change the Animation type of my animation clips to 2 so I can drag them into the Animator. But what do I do now?

Comment: I added a image of what the  controller should be similar to after you correctly create the clips. I would re-work the animations so they are created properly and wont have unexpected behavior like moving to the position they were created at. If you have trouble just start with a few small things like a coin collect animation and work up to more complex objects after you have a firm understanding

Comment: Justin thank you. You see im a student Engineer. I figure out how to do it with Scripting. I know it would be easier with animator but for me some lines of code is simplier than Animator. When I'll start a new project I'll use the Animator Compoment. Thank you agian for your time.